# Bulk delete documents of a specific type in elasticsearch

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I have an index called "animals" in elasticsearch. That contains several documents of type "dogs".
I want to delete all "dogs" documents in "animals" index. I am using python elasticsearch package. 
My python code is as follows:

```
connection = Elasticsearch([{"host": "myhost", "port": "myport" } ])
body = {} # What should I put in the body???
connection.bulk(body, index="animals", doc_type="dogs", ignore=[400, 404])
```

Here I don't know what do I need to put in the `body`. Can anyone help me out?

Bulk method is defined at [https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/client/**init**.py#L1002](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py#L1002)

Answer (score 0):

There is no api in `elasticsearch-py` to delete all documents of a type. This is because Elasticsearch 2.x onwards there is no api to delete a `type`. 
From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_types_may_no_longer_be_deleted)

> In 1.x it was possible to delete a type
>   mapping, along with all of the documents of that type, using the
>   delete mapping API. This is no longer supported, because remnants of
>   the fields in the type could remain in the index, causing corruption
>   later on.
>
> Instead, if you need to delete a type mapping, you should reindex to a
>   new index which does not contain the mapping. If you just need to
>   delete the documents that belong to that type, then use the
>   delete-by-query plugin instead.